# Unlock account using security Q&A using AD .net membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have a .net web app that uses AD to manager the users, I got the security question and answer working to reset the password (followed this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998360.aspx)

The problem:
Currently AD's `Lockout-Threshold` is set to `0` so the user can try to login as many times they want. If I set the `Lockout-Threshold` to `5` attempts and the account is locked then the security question and answer don't work, cannot reset the password if AD locks the account.

Is there way to lock the account after 5 attempts but allow the user to go though the password Q&A process?

Thanks,
Tarek

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you are authenticating into the web page with the same account that needs to be unlocked.  This would be a catch-22.  You have two options:

1. Make the account unlock page completely unauthenticated. This would allow anyone access, so that needs to be considered. If it is only hosted on the intranet, that would at least reduce outside attacks.
2. Allow people to select a different user than themselves to unlock.  This way a user could go to a coworkers desk and access the page.  Alternatively this could be used by the HR Dept.